# Angular UI-Grid cell edit input deleting on scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular ui-grid in my application. If you double click the edit column to enable cell edit, you get a number input field. Input a number in the field and then scroll in the grid so that the cell is no longer visible. When you scroll back up the input is no longer there.

In my app I have another editable cell that contains a dropdown and that doesn't disappear. Just the number input field.

Here is a plnkr demoing my issue : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/8f4MrC2xJLJ3kYBQzG8c?p=preview

I tried setting ng-model to :

```
ng-model = $scope.edit;
```

and

```
ng-model = $scope.gridOptions.data.offset;
```

and neither seems to make a difference.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: Your plunker seems to work for me (FF 43). Maybe I don't understand your question?

Comment: @mainguy once you edit the cell by selecting a number, scroll the grid down and then come back up and the edited cell is now blank

Comment: Try it in Firefox. This seems to be okay, at least in your plunker.

Comment: Its working fine for me in your plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to use a custom input field.

All I had to do was set the type: 'number' in the column definition and it gave me the number input that doesn't disappear on scroll.